# Datagrid to C1PdfDocument (ComponentOne)

Tags: pdf, datagrid, grid, componentone

I am not sure if anyone around here is familiar with ComponentOne's c1pdfdocument, let's hope so.

All I want to achieve is to get a datagrid/table/ on my PDF. I have my data all ready to go in a DataTable but I have not a single clue how to add it to my c1pdfdocument and I can't find it on the net.

Greetings,
Gerben

Answer (score 0):

I've written a few samples converting a C1DataGrid and C1FlexGrid to PDF. Although, only Silverlight and WPF. My solution uses the GetPageImages method from the grid control to generate each page, so it would not work in any other platform. Check out the Generating PDF topic in this blog post.

[a print preview solution for flexgrid and datagrid](http://our.componentone.com/2012/09/26/a-print-preview-solution-for-flexgrid-and-datagrid/)

And here's another blog post that is specifically for C1DataGrid in WPF. This one goes row by row, cell by cell generating the output so if you were using a standard datagrid you could use this as a better example.

[saving c1datagrid for wpf as Pdf](http://our.componentone.com/2012/03/26/saving-c1datagrid-for-wpf-as-pdf/)